# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c# error

Tags: c#, sql

I need to check if a record is saved into database or not. If it was saved in database open another form, else show a message that it is not in database.
If the record is not in database I get this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
This is my code please help me to find the error here:

```
string cmdStr = "Select NO from COM_LIST_EXPORT where NO = '" + txtNO.Text + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, CN);
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (count == Convert.ToInt32(txtNO.Text))
{
    Archive_Sader dd = new Archive_Sader();
    dd.Show();
}

else
{
    MessageBox.Show("please save first");
}
```

Comment: I love a nice bit of SQL Injection.

Comment: I would have  alook at using parameters for your query. That is vulnerable to SQLi

Comment: Where do you create the object `CN`?
Also take a look parameterised queries.

Comment: Canonical answer: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` returns `null` when no records found.

So when trying to cast `null -> int` you get a `NullReferenceException`

Try this instead.

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

`Convert.ToInt32` will return `0` when parameter is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

From [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Return Value
>
> The first column of the first row in the result set, **or a null
>   reference if the result set is empty.**

That's why when there is no row as a result, you actually try to convert `null` to `Int32`.

Looks like you need to change your line like;

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Because [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `0` when parameter is `null`.

> Return Value
>
> A 32-bit signed integer that is equivalent to the number in value, **or
>   0 (zero) if value is null.**

And you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

For example;

```
string cmdStr = "Select NO from COM_LIST_EXPORT where NO = @NO";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, CN);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO", txtNO.Text);
...
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this.. My +1..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Looks like haters gonna hate `:)`